# How to check if table exist in snowpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to check if a table exisit in snowflake using snowpark api in the below procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE table_merge(keys Array)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE PYTHON
  RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
  PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
  HANDLER = 'reverse_str'
AS
$$
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import when_matached
def table_merge(session,keys):
  session.use_database(mydb)
  session.use_schema(myschema)
  table= session.sql(s"SHOW TABLES LIKE {}").format(mytable)
  if table_exist:
      do something
  else:
      do different

  return 'Pass'
$$;
```

The above procedure return the syntax error

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python you should use f-string format, so this rows should be, also you need to execute the query, so you can use .execute()

```
table= session.sql(f"SHOW TABLES LIKE {mytable}").execute()
```

And not

```
table= session.sql(s"SHOW TABLES LIKE {}").format(mytable)
```

This is the syntax error you are getting.